# Programming R : how to put multi-plots in a same coordinates?

Tags: r

I don't know how to put four plots(y=3^x, y=(1/3)^x, y=(3/2)^x, y=e^x) into a same coordinates. 
I typed:

```
a = function(x){y=3^x}
b = function{y=(1/3)^x}
c = function{y=(3/2)^x}
d = function(x){exp(x)}
plot(-4:4, a, b, c, d)
```

but it did not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `add=TRUE` option, Also you have your second and third functions written wrong (they take no parameters). So you have:

```
a = function(x){y=3^x}
b = function(x){y=(1/3)^x}
c = function(x){y=(3/2)^x}
d = function(x){exp(x)}
```

and you plot using:

```
plot(a , -4 , 4)
plot(b , -4 , 4, add=TRUE)
plot(c , -4 , 4, add=TRUE)
plot(d , -4 , 4, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However there is one problem. When I make plots in a same coordinates,y label(name) becomes a. How can I change "a" to "y"?

Comment: @Serendipity add the option ylab="y" in the first plot. `plot(a , -4 , 4 , ylab = "y")`

Comment: Thank you. I got to be able to solve this problem.You helped me a lot. I appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: You can also plot the expressions directly, without creating functions, using `curve(...)`, as in: `curve(3^x , -4 , 4, ylab="y"); curve((1/3)^x,add=TRUE); curve((3/2)^x,add=TRUE); curve(exp(x),add=TRUE)`